# How to get Jersey client to write `[` and `]` around root request entity?

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, jersey

This really simple request is giving me a headache...

I'm trying to `POST` data into InfluxDB using the Jersey client.

They want the data in this format

```
[
  {
    "name": "log_lines",
    "columns": ["time", "line"],
    "points": [
      [1400425947368, "here's some useful log info"]
    ]
  }
]
```

So my entity looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class InfluxDbStat implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement
    public String name;
    @XmlElement
    public String[] columns;
    @XmlElement
    public String[] points;
}
```

Which translates to:

```
{  
   "name":"pointcut_performance",
   "columns":[  
      "time",
      "pointcut",
      "length"
   ],
   "points":[  
      "1412098229880",
      "com.xxx.notes.restapi.NoteTakerController.postNote(ApiNote)",
      "105"
   ]
}
```

And I'm invoking the endpoint like this:

```
influxDbResource.queryParam("u", influxDbUser).queryParam("p", influxDbPassword).queryParam("time_precision", "ms").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(influxDbStat);
```

How do I get it to print square brackets as the root?

Comment: Assuming `influxDbStat` is a reference to a `InfluxDbStat` instance, instead, wrap it in a `List`. `Array.asList(influxDbStat)` and pass that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post my answer in hopes that someone with a similar issue will some day benefit from this.

First, I switched to the official InfluxDB Java client, which actually works just fine. I was quite happy using this solution, but it involved pulling in another dependency to my project which I wasn't particularly happy about. There is also an open bug, in which milliseconds are interpreted as microseconds (https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-java/issues/13). Kinda a party crasher.

The second way is a little bit of trickery. Sotirios Delimanolis provided me a clue in his comment. First, wrap the response object in an array: `new InfluxDbStat[]{influxDbStat};` Second, screws JAXB. None of the marshallers I could find, Jackson, Jettison, Moxy, (sadly, even yes the trusty Eclipse Moxy) fail to produce "normal" interest-hipster-like JSON. All is not lost though, we were already pulling in GSON transitively as a dependency, so we decided to just make in a declared dependency and use it. So, just do a `gson.toJson(new InfluxDbStat[]{influxDbStat})` and you're good to go!

One other bug we discovered from my first post is that the `points` variable actually needs to be declared as `public int[][] points`, since InfluxDB allows you to submit multiple rows at once.

Anyway good luck and happy InfluxDBing!